# How to properly configure Lambda Function provisionedConcurrentExecutions?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have a lambda function integrated with API Gateway. I'm trying to configure `provisionedConcurrentExecutions` for that function without success. Cloud Watch contains the following log record:

> REPORT RequestId: 6d818a07-cee8-41f8-aedc-9df9b2aa1a75    Duration:
> 4276.27 ms    Billed Duration: 4277 ms    Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 107 MB Init Duration: 3536.87 ms

As I understand, if `provisionedConcurrentExecutions` is configured properly, `Init Duration` should not be there.

I'm the only person calling the function, so there is only one concurrent request.

I'm using AWS CDK to configure the API Gatway and the function. Here is the code:

```
import { Duration, Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda'
import { LambdaIntegration, RestApi } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';



export class ApiLambdaStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const api = new RestApi(this, 'OpenDataApi', {
        restApiName: `REST API`
    });
    this.configureLambda(api, "MyLambdaFunction", "my-lambda-function");
  }

  private configureLambda(api: RestApi, methodName: string, path: string, memorySize: number = 256): void {
    const lambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, `${methodName}LambdaFunction`, {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_6,
        handler: `ApiGatewayLambda::ApiGatewayLambda.Functions::${methodName}`,
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('ApiGatewayLambda'),
        timeout: Duration.seconds(30),
        memorySize: memorySize,
        reservedConcurrentExecutions: 4
    });

    const version = lambdaFunction.currentVersion;
    const alias = new lambda.Alias(this, `${methodName}Al`, {
      aliasName: `${methodName}Al`,
      version: version,
      provisionedConcurrentExecutions: 2
    });

    const lambdaFunctionIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(alias);
    const resource = api.root.addResource(path);
    resource.addMethod('POST', lambdaFunctionIntegration);
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? How to properly configure `provisionedConcurrentExecutions`?

I'm using PostMan to call API Gateway, and the first request takes about 10 seconds, subsequent requests are under 1 second. If I wait some time, then it takes 10 seconds again. So something is wrong, provisioned concurrency doesn't seem to produce any effect.

Comment: [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) says that *configuring provisioned concurrency incurs charges to your AWS account.* so it should be shown in the "billed durations" even if the billed duration does not match the actual execution duration (since the init happened beforehand)

Comment: @apokryfos I'm talking about 'Init Duration'  not billed duration. Anyway. I'm using PostMan to call API Gateway, and the first request takes about 10 seconds, subsecuent requests are under 1 second. If I wait some time, then it takes 10 seconds again. So something is wrong, provisioned concurrency doesn't seem to produce any effect.

Comment: Check the `AWS_LAMBDA_INITIALIZATION_TYPE` environment variable in the lambda - is it `on-demand` or `provisioned-concurrency`?

Comment: Also - try setting the `AWS_LAMBDA_DOTNET_PREJIT` environment variable in the lambda config to `Always` and see if that helps.

Comment: @gshpychka. Thank you. Very valuable information. Incidentally, `AWS_LAMBDA_INITIALIZATION_TYPE` value is `provisioned-concurrency` so it seems I configured it correctly. However there is still time differences between the first and subsequent requests. I enabled `PublishReadyToRun` , it helped a little. `AWS_LAMBDA_DOTNET_PREJIT` doesn't seem to help too much. If you make your comments an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.